# Is there a way to make google sheets import range function stick to the range when it changes in the source sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

**Context**

So I have been using query and importRange to pull data from my other sheets in conjunction with importRange. This is because importRange did not get all the data from the spreadsheet. But it seems as though when I re-open the sheet, after leaving it for a day, the data in the new spreadsheet moves cells from where I placed them.

I have time-series data that have different dates and so the data is placed in different cells to each other relative to the dates. I have placed an example below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So for instance in the second picture, the data for Softcat will move to a different cell location rather than where I imported it from. The same for Trainline (the third picture).

**Problem**

1. Is there a function I can use to prevent it from leaving these cells that I have attached them to? Especially for the ones at the lower end of the spreadsheet?
2. Should I move data in the source sheet (move around columns), is there a way to make importRange or some other means to stick with this column that has this specific data set? I tried fixing it with the '$' sign but it still displays different data from the listed column reference.

[This is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ogWvvd-pJfhcVsf16Ft-aHvMNqnxKs-YjCtrQvh4xQc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I have attached it with an example of what I am talking about under the Softcat column

Comment: If you set a formula to a cell, it shouldn't change the cell it's on. Do you have an attached script or add-on? Are you inserting rows? You should try reloading the page and see if it updates. If that doesn't work, I'd try to make a new spreadsheet with a completely different name, add the functions there, save it and see what happens. Do not share it with anyone and, if possible, add it in a folder that's not shared (to discard possible problems with multiple people viewing/editing).

Comment: Did you try named ranges? Importrange with range in form "Sheet!A1:A" works the same way as Sheet!$A$1:$A inside the sheet. If you change this to named range - lets say "data" and reference under this name inside the source file will change, you will still get range that you need.

Comment: let me ask you this: on which row do you place the softcat formula? (as of today I see it on row 1733) and when you place it then the formula will move down a row on the next day or the referenced range Softcat!D4:D will move down the row and it becomes Softcat!D5:D

Comment: Thank you all for your response :). @Marti Currently there are no background scripts in this sheet. Perhaps the price sheet however, the sheet displaying the data has no scripts. Also, the folder is not shared with anyone.

Comment: @Krzysztof Dołęgowski This looks promising for the second one, I am currently trying this out. Though not sure for the first one, time will tell. But will give it a shot.

Comment: @player0 it was in the same cell but it can sometimes change.

Comment: @Desmond I think what player0 meant was to ask what is moving: the query formulas on the spreadsheet, or the data that the query functions are changing values? (the formulas are not where you left them in the spreadsheet, or the queried data is not the same?). That a good point and it's quite important, actually.

Comment: @Marti Ahh I see. Well the formula locations moves on occasion. But the values are the same as the source sheet.

Comment: @Desmond It's really weird... I'd try to make a copy manually, copying the formulas one by one and see if this happens again in the new file.

Comment: @Marti Have tried it, will get back to you in a few days to see if this works

Comment: So I found out why this happens. The date column keeps updating because of the function used to generate the data `=GOOGLEFINANCE($A$1, "price", TODAY()-4380,TODAY())` So the price is dynamic and constantly chainging, moving one day ahead. But it seems the data on the other columns are not moving in tandem despite being calculated from the source data. Any solutions following on this?